# How to parameterize parametric column type in PostgreSQL `execute format()`?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've got some PL/pgSQL code like this:

```sql
DECLARE
    v_schema_name pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname%type := 'my_schema';
    v_table_name pg_catalog.pg_tables.tablename%type := 'my_table';
    v_column_name pg_catalog.pg_attribute.attname%type := 'my_column';
    v_new_type TEXT := 'DECIMAL(16, 12)';
BEGIN
    -- Omitted other code using v_new_type
    EXECUTE format(
        'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I TYPE %I',
        v_schema_name,
        v_table_name,
        v_column_name,
        v_new_type
    );
END;
```

This results in the following error:

> ERROR: type "DECIMAL(16, 12)" does not exist

I tried changing the last part of the format string to `%L` instead, but that results in this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "'DECIMAL(16, 12)'"

How do I parameterize this query? Do I need to break it into three parts or something?

Update:

- ["The types decimal and numeric are equivalent."](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-numeric.html)
- The `numeric` type can be found with `select * from pg_catalog.pg_type where typname = 'numeric';`, so `v_new_type pg_catalog.pg_type.typname%type := 'decimal';` should be usable.

Comment: A type declaration is neither an identifier nor a literal. Use `%s`.

Comment: @klin Nice, that worked! Do you want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type specification in Postgres can be very complex due ANSI SQL types like `DOUBLE PRECISION` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Parsing of these types should be supported by Postgres's parser, and then this syntax is allowed only for built-in types. For more common types the type specification has two parts: identifier and optional type modifier. So your code should to look like:

```
DECLARE
    v_schema_name pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname%type := 'my_schema';
    v_table_name pg_catalog.pg_tables.tablename%type := 'my_table';
    v_column_name pg_catalog.pg_attribute.attname%type := 'my_column';
    v_new_type TEXT := 'decimal'; -- Postgres uses lowercase notation
    v_new_type_mod TEXT := '(16, 12)'
BEGIN
    -- Omitted other code using v_new_type
    EXECUTE format(
        'ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I TYPE %I%s',
        v_schema_name,
        v_table_name,
        v_column_name,
        v_new_type,
        v_new_type_mod
    );
END;
```

Note - you can use %s like proposes @klin, and you can sanitize it by casting to regtype. But it requires correctly entered type name.

```
DECLARE
  ...
  v_new_type TEXT := 'decimal(16, 12)';
BEGIN
  -- sanitize data type
  PERFORM v_new_type::regtype;
  EXECUTE format(... TYPE %s',
     ...
     v_new_type);
END;
```

Comment: I'll upvote when I have time to verify, but this looks like a nice solution!

Comment: Flipping this around I was able to use `v_new_type regtype := 'decimal(16, 12)';` with the `%I` format string, and `v_new_type::text` where I needed the type as a string.

Answer (score 1):

A type declaration is neither an identifier nor a literal. Use `%s`.

Comment: Hm. A type name *is* an identifier. You could be a little more verbose, for example suggest that the type name and the type modifiers be passed in separate variables.

Comment: I'm not sure it's really worth complicating an inherently simple thing.

Comment: You have a point. But what if `v_new_type` is something like `my-custom-enum`?

Comment: `v_new_type text := '"my-custom-enum"';` I used to tell my students - don't call an object "my-object". But if you have such a whim, just remember that it is "my-object", not my-object. It seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, that will work, but it relies on the user adding double quotes herself. If you go the slightly more complicated way of separating data type and type modifiers, you could use the `%I` format for the data type and avoid the problem. That also prevents deliberate SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Of course, Pavel's proposal is the most correct, formal solution. Note however, from a practical point of view, it does not add anything new to the problem, except that it contains additional code. Contrary to expectations, it does not prevent potential SQL injection attacks. (This is not a criticism, but rather a continuation of a loose discussion about the superiority of practice over theory).

Comment: @klin - the typemod can be more easy checked, because there can be only numbers and coma. It is interesting, and it hasn't simply solution, because Postgres has not data type for holding type + type mod info. I enhanced my example about safe variant.